# 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, sdk, syntax-error

My code is the fllowing and error i get is 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List'

```
 List<String> store=[];
     void getData() async {
       await for(var snapshot in _firestore.collection('users').snapshots()){
         for(var phon in snapshot.documents){
         store=(phon.data['Name']);
         print(store);
       }
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> store=[];
String name;
     void getData() async {
       await for(var snapshot in _firestore.collection('users').snapshots()){
         for(var phon in snapshot.documents){
         name=(phon.data['Name']);
         print(name);
       }
   } 
}
```

What you are doing is storing a `String` `(phon.data['Name'])` in a `List`.
I have this sample code which has `String` named `name` and now storing String`name` in `phon.data['Name']`. you can also do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because in `store=(phon.data['Name']);`you try to set the value of the whole list as a string. Instead you should've set only the value of one of the lists fields as a string. For example `store[0]=(phon.data['Name']);`

Answer (score 0):

Change `store=(phon.data['Name'])` to `store.add(phon.data['Name'])`
You are trying to  assign a single string (I assume that is what phon.data['Name'] is) to a List object.